# I have an issue with the changeStock method of a Product class in views.py in Django

Tags: python, django

I am doing a Product class in Django for fun and I have ran into a problem regarding changing the Product's (the model name) regarding its variable qtyOnHand, which is used to check to see how much of that product is in stock.

The goal is to change the product's qtyOnHand by a specified amount using the changeStock method and redirect to the home page where the updated qtyOnHand will be stored. The amount can be negative if taking out stock, and +ve if receiving stock.  The error I got when typing in the URL
http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/1/changeStock/2 is unsupported operand types for +: int and str, which was

Here's my code for the changeStock method in the views.py.  The comments there are to guide my approach to the problem.

```
# Change the stock of a specific product by the specified amount.  A -ve number means that you are taking out product, 
# while a +ve one means you are receiving that product.
def changeStock(request, pk, amount):
    # We need the id of a specific product, plus we have to check if it's not found.
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
    
    # Then we have to update its qtyOnHand.
    product.qtyOnHand = product.qtyOnHand + amount -> error occurs at this line
    
    # Then we have to save the changes to the database.
    product.save()
    
    # Then we have to redirect to the home page.
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'product': product})
```

Here is my urls.py, which is used to store my URLs.  The part (?P-?\d+) is used to include numbers that are positive and negative numbers.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from inventories import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^products/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.product_topics, name='product_topics'),
    url(r'^products/(?P<pk>\d+)/new/$', views.new_product, name='new_product'),
    url(r'^products/(?P<pk>\d+)/changeStock/(?P<amount>-?\d+)$', views.changeStock, name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

In my home.py, which shows all the products

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block breadcrumb %}
  <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Products</li>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
      <tr>
        <th>Products</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Quantity on Hand</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for product in products %}
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a href="{% url 'product_topics' product.pk %}">{{ product.name }}</a>
            <small class="text-muted d-block">{{ product.description }}</small>
          </td>
          <td class="align-middle">
            {{ product.price }}
          </td>
          <td class="align-middle">{{ product.qtyOnHand }} </td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>

{% endblock %}
```

And here's models.py for my Product class

```py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=4000)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19,decimal_places=2)
    qtyOnHand = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Can someone show me what this error means, and how I can fix it?

Comment: product.qtyOnHand is an integer.

Comment: I believe the problem is `product.qtyOnHand + amount` should be `product.qtyOnHand + int(amount)`. By default all parameters passed to a Django view are strings

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this problem, mattyx17.  I changed it to int(amount) and it solved everything.  Turns out this is the issue when you are adding an int to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passed parameter is taken as `string` in view.so convert it to `int`. `product.qtyOnHand` is always int as defined in model.So not add `string` type to `int`.Please change `product.qtyOnHand = product.qtyOnHand + amount`  to

```
product.qtyOnHand = product.qtyOnHand + int(amount)
```

I suggest like this.

Comment: So this implies that the error was caused by a type casting issue.